# How to migrate MySQL REPLACE to TYPO3 QueryBuilder?

Tags: php, typo3, query-builder, typo3-8.x

I'm refactoring a pretty ancient TYPO3 extension codebase from pibase to extbase. One part is to rework the old MySQL approach from

```
$GLOBALS["TYPO3_DB"]->sql_query("...")
```

to

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('...');
```

I have a query like that one and do not know how to do that with the querybuilder neither I found something in the docs

```
SELECT * FROM $this->db_name.Profs WHERE (REPLACE(RelatedUser, ' ', '-') = '" . ($this->tOnly($name)) . "' OR REPLACE(RelatedUser, ' ', '-') = '" . ($this->tOnly($pre)) . "') AND ((ID NOT IN (" . implode(',', $exclude_ids) . ")) AND ID NOT IN (" . implode(',', $this->locked) . ")) LIMIT 1
```

Every part is clear on how to handle except the REPLACE function - it takes a value of the given row and manipulates that on the fly for comparison.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try with executeQuery
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Connection $connection */
$connection = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable($table);
$rows = $connection->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1')->fetchAll();

Comment: ye that should work but it looks like all security relevant steps are skipped? for now i just switched the values like im not manipulating the row values i just put my hands on the actual value $name and manipulate the format to match the database value so i dont have to deal with a replace at all

Comment: This seems to be the better way :)